# Properties a topological space must satisfy for it to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I was reading about Brouwer's theorem and the book I was studying from pointed the following interesting consequence:

> A topological space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set if and only if it is non-empty, perfect, compact, totally disconnected, and metrizable

That made me wonder if there is an equivalent result regarding the real numbers with the Euclidean topology. This is, is there a set of properties a topological space must satisfy for it to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: connected, non-compact, second countable, Hausdorff, and locally homeomorphic to the real line

Comment: @CSquared "locally homeomorphic to the real line" is not a very good description

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered here on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76134/topological-characterisation-of-the-real-line One of the possible characterizations: connected, locally connected, separable, $T_3$ such that removal of any point leaves two connected components.